# Timestamp Conditional Groupby Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset looking something like this:

```
ID DATE       Amt
1  1999-07-02 1000
1  1999-07-02 120
1  1999-08-03 500
1  1999-09-05 1000
```

There are multiple IDs. I want to group these rows by their IDs ,then calculate total amount for each month. Final dataset should resemble something like this:

```
ID Total_Month02 Total_Month03 Total_Month04 Total_Month05
1  1120          500            0            1000
```

There are 12 such months, for which totals are to be computed. I tried using GroupBy on the IDs but I am not sure how to do the aggregation using the timestamps. How does one do this in Pandas?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format='%Y-%d-%m')

out = df.set_index('DATE').groupby('ID')['Amt'].resample('M').sum().unstack()
out.columns = out.columns.strftime("Total_Month%m")
```

```
>>> out
DATE  Total_Month02  Total_Month03  Total_Month04  Total_Month05
ID
1              1120            500              0           1000
```